# Validate SQL Password Against Password Policy

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, passwords, policy

I have several windows applications that can be access through an SQL account. I need to validate the user password against Local Security Policy of the Server without modfiying the password itself.

What I require is an SQL statement that return a boolean value whether or not the password is according to the server policy or not.

Is it something possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to validate a SQL login password against the policy or how to validate a password managed by your own application? The first is certainly [possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161959.aspx), the second will probably require you to [program](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370661(v=vs.85).aspx) the feature yourself.

Comment: I am asking on how to validate an SQL Login Password. Ie: If a password is according to the password policy or not.

I don't want to Alter the login in anyway!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the extra information in your comment, it seems that you want to validate existing SQL login passwords against the Windows password policy, but without making any changes to the logins.

This is probably not possible because there is no way to retrieve a SQL login password, so there is no way to validate them yourself programmatically. However, according to the documentation, the check [is on by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), so it's possible that all your passwords are already compliant with the OS security policy, unless you've deliberately set this off and then on for some logins.

If you need to ensure that all login passwords comply with the policy, the best way to make sure is to set the check on for all logins (if it isn't already) and force a password change. Even better, stop using SQL logins and use Windows logins instead, although I know that isn't possible in every situation.